# Can't check out file with Office interop

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office-interop, checkout

I'm using Microsoft's Word's interop command CheckOut(path) to check out files from a SharePoint mapped drive.

The credentials for the mapped drive are different than my signed in user. However, this doesn't prevent me from checking-in new files. These files appear under the credentials of the SharePoint mapped drive as expected.

However, for some files that have already been checked-in, the command fails.

```
// This will throw an interop exception
var docApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application { Visible = false };
docApp.Documents.CheckOut(pathToFile);
```

I know the files aren't locked by another user, since Microsoft Word can check out these files without issue.

My question is, how do I reliably check out files the same way Microsoft Word does?

Comment: Microsoft Word create a temporary file in the folder that starts with a tilde that create the lock for read only.  The only way of doing exactly the same as Word is to open the file.

Comment: Unfortunately my version of Office (Office 2013) isn't leaving the ~ cache file. Apparently it's storing the cache file somewhere, but I don't know where.

Comment: You may not see the lock file if it was created by another user.  Try using an admin account.

Comment: I do have admin rights and I created the document. Couldn't find the backup anywhere. The SharePoint credentials are different than my computer credentials. Is that relevant?

I tried using CheckInWithVersion(). However, VersionType is only defined as object.

I tried reverting, but couldn't find the API.

Comment: Is file on local drive or a network drive?  If local drive if you reboot machine can you write?